# Optionally pass an argument in a bash script

Tags: bash, rsync

I would like to use custom identity file when using rsync, but only if the file exists, otherwise I don't want to bother with custom ssh command for rsync. I am having problems with quotes. See examples.

Desired command if identity file exists

```
rsync -e "ssh -i '/tmp/id_rsa'" /tmp/dir/ u@h:/tmp/dir
```

Desired command if identity file does not exist

```
rsync /tmp/dir/ u@h:/tmp/dir
```

I wanted to create a variable that would contain `-e "ssh -i '/tmp/id_rsa'"` and use it as follows

```
rsync ${identityArg} /tmp/dir/ u@h:/tmp/dir
```

This variable would be either empty or contain desired ssh command.

An example way I fill the variable (I have tried many ways)

```
IDENTITY_FILE="/tmp/id_rsa"
if [ -f "${IDENTITY_FILE}" ]; then
  identityArg="-e 'ssh -i \"${IDENTITY_FILE}\"'"
fi
```

The problem is that quotes are always wrong in the command and I end up with commands similar to these ones (`set -x` is set in the script and this is the output)

```
rsync -e '\ssh' -i '"/tmp/id_rsa"'\''' /tmp/dir/ u@h:/tmp/dir
```

There is something I do not get about quotation in bash. If you have any good resource about usage of single and double quotes in bash script I would like to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add two positional parameters: `-e` and `ssh -i '/tmp/id_rsa'`, where `/tmp/id_rsa` is an expanded variable. You should use an array for this:

```sh
args=(/tmp/dir/ u@h:/tmp/dir)
idfile=/tmp/id_rsa

# Let [[ ... ]] do the quoting
if [[ -f $idfile ]]; then
    # Prepend two parameters to args array
    args=(-e "ssh -i '$idfile'" "${args[@]}")
fi

rsync "${args[@]}"
```

I'm not convinced the inner single quotes are necessary for `ssh -i`, but this expands to exactly the commands shown in the question.

Comment: Awesome, the single quotes are not needed. The question then is: What happens if path to id_rsa contains whitespace character, e.g. `/t\ m\ p/id_rsa`?

Comment: always (mostly) double-quote you vars: ```-f "${idfile}"```

Comment: @vgersh99 That's not necessary in `[[ ... ]]`, but doesn't hurt either.

Comment: @SamoPoláček If you have spaces in the path, then you do need the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
id=/tmp/id_rsa
[[ -e $id ]] && o1='-e' o2="ssh -i '$id'"
echo $o1 "$o2" /tmp/dir/ u@h:/tmp/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to properly escape quotes is tricky. Better to try to leverage existing constructs. Few alternatives, depending on the situations

If the name of the identity file only contain simple characters (no spaces, wildcard, etc.) consider not wrapping it in quotes. In this case, you can

```
IDENTITY_FILE="/tmp/id_rsa"
if [ -f "${IDENTITY_FILE}" ]; then
  identityArg="-e 'ssh -i ${IDENTITY_FILE}'"
fi
...
rsync $identityArg ...
```

Another option is to always pass in the command (ssh or 'ssh -I ...'). This will automatically take care for special characters in the identity file.

```
IDENTITY_FILE="/tmp/id_rsa"
if [ -f "${IDENTITY_FILE}" ]; then
  identityArg="-i '${IDENTITY_FILE}'"
fi
rsync -e "ssh $identityArg" ...
```

Third alternative is to use array to create the arguments to `rsync`, and let the shell escape the characters as needed. This will allow any character in the identity file.

```
IDENTITY_FILE="/tmp/id_rsa"
if [ -f "${IDENTITY_FILE}" ]; then
  identityArg=(-e "ssh -i '${IDENTITY_FILE}'")
fi
rsync "${identityArg[@]}" ...
```